# I fails to plot_tree() when I use lightgbm

Tags: graphviz, lightgbm

I fails to plot_tree when I use lightgbm.

I upload traceback as an image, because I cannot download my code from server.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Try using cut / paste to get the trace and code as in this way it is highly unlikely people will look at the problem as it is hardly readable.

Comment: @albert I'm sorry. I'm working on my jupyter notebook in the separate server and lab-top. The lab-top cannot be connected with internet. The lab-top can only be connected to corporate server due to security issue. So taking a picture for the error was the only choice I could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue in the past.
If your aim is to investigate which features each tree splits on and which value it splits on you can use an alternative approach:

After instantiating a LightGBM classifier and fitting it to the training data you can then use the [`trees_to_dataframe()`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.trees_to_dataframe) method of the booster of the classifer. This retrieves the data in a relatively easy-to-read format. Even though it doesn't create a plot, the resulting dataframe can be used to investigate the tree in more detail.

Here is an example using the `load_breast_cancer` dataset from sklearn

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data['data'], data['target']
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=data['feature_names'])

clf = LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

clf.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```

Output:

|  | tree_index | node_depth | node_index | left_child | right_child | parent_index | split_feature | split_gain | threshold | decision_type | missing_direction | missing_type | value | weight | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0-S0 | 0-S1 | 0-S3 | None | worst_area | 3.925050e+02 | 868.2000 | <= | left | None | 0.521150 | 0.000000 | 569 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0-S1 | 0-S4 | 0-S2 | 0-S0 | worst_concave_points | 6.169360e+01 | 0.1358 | <= | left | None | 0.641339 | 89.298200 | 382 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 0-S4 | 0-S5 | 0-L5 | 0-S1 | area_error | 1.586540e+00 | 34.7300 | <= | left | None | 0.672849 | 78.077500 | 334 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 | 0-S5 | 0-S8 | 0-S6 | 0-S4 | worst_texture | 7.523920e-01 | 30.0800 | <= | left | None | 0.676446 | 73.402200 | 314 |
| 4 | 0 | 5 | 0-S8 | 0-L0 | 0-L9 | 0-S5 | mean_radius | 2.842170e-14 | 13.4950 | <= | left | None | 0.680533 | 63.116600 | 270 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5589 | 99 | 4 | 99-S24 | 99-L18 | 99-S27 | 99-S17 | mean_texture | 2.184820e-09 | 15.0450 | <= | left | None | -0.100054 | 0.013308 | 123 |
| 5590 | 99 | 5 | 99-L18 | None | None | 99-S24 | None | NaN | NaN | None | None | None | -0.100125 | 0.003284 | 3 |
| 5591 | 99 | 5 | 99-S27 | 99-L25 | 99-L28 | 99-S24 | worst_radius | 6.243950e-10 | 16.3200 | <= | left | None | -0.100031 | 0.010024 | 120 |
| 5592 | 99 | 6 | 99-L25 | None | None | 99-S27 | None | NaN | NaN | None | None | None | -0.100063 | 0.003757 | 9 |
| 5593 | 99 | 6 | 99-L28 | None | None | 99-S27 | None | NaN | NaN | None | None | None | -0.100012 | 0.006267 | 111 |